# Possibly non-intrusive method to change complete android application code with a library

Tags: java, android

I'm having quite tough problem while developing a testing framework for android apps. The text got a bit long so the actual question is in bold for those that don't want to read the context.

Basically, what I'd like to achieve right now is to trace user activity while he's using the application as one of the features. There's my app that manages context data all the time and developer's app - the one being tested. My idea to do this was to get coordinates where user touched the screen along with taking a screenshot simultaneously. Then I'd use the coordinates to mark the spot on the screenshot to get the idea of what user was doing the whole time with the app. Take hints on user experience and trace crashes.

Non-system apps cannot take a screenshot for security reasons, but application itself can take a screenshot of its Activities without much trouble for non-rooted users, e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/944734). My only hope here is to interfere with developers' code to implement the functionality of doing so while my testing app is running. **Each Activity then would have to extend my overridden Activity instead of regular one, implement an interface, implement broadcast receiver etc.**

**I am going to write a library for developer who would like his app to be tested with my framework. I'd like it to do the job for me and be as non-intrusive as it's possible for him to use. How to achieve that the best way?**

**Ideal case would assume linking the library to project with maybe a small addition in manifest that'd get the job done and after just unlinking, removing that bit of xml in manifest for production.**

That's an open question. I don't expect any bits of code, but some nifty Java trick, Android OS functionality or even completely other approach that'd solve my problem

I tried to be as clear as possible with the question, but that's a quite tough matter for me to describe so that could have turned out contrary. Don't hesitate to ask me for more details, to speak my mind more clearly or even rewrite the question. Thank you all very much for help!